# Script in JS not work on another pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have

```
<div class="p-cart-button left tar large-5 medium-5 small-5">
     <span class="button-product-wrap button-wrap">
           <a class="button-content-product button-content small button" href="#" title="Detail">Detail</a>
     </span>
</div>
```

I want to change "Detail" in a class, so I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.p-cart-button a:contains("Detail")').text('Detail a varianty');});
```

It's worked nice but just on refreshed page. If I go to page 2 in the shop, it doesn't change but JS is working.

What should I do to make it work? Any ideas?

You can see example there -> [EXAMPLE](https://www.ziskoun.cz/sperky/)

If you go to page 2, script doesn't work.

Comment: The script still works on page 2 but it needs to be executed again as the page 2 elements were not on the DOM when it was run on the first page. Is this the issue you are having?

Comment: DOM ready is only ever called once on page load, your loading the other pages using ajax / or fetch.  So of course DOM ready is not going to fire again..  Like @ZekeSnider has pointed out, you will need to execute the above on page navigation, look into your page loading script, often they will have an event you can attach onto.

Comment: Hm, sounds too hard for me, I am just beginner in JS. But like @ZekeSnider says, it's my issue.